# How to seperate C# data connection code into a class file

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=c://library//lib.mdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from entry where LTRIM(subjet)=?", cn);
    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", comboBox1.Text);
    DataSet fg = new DataSet();
    cmd.Fill(fg);

    label1.Text = "No. of Rows:-    " + fg.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = fg.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a simple, small application then something like this would suffice...

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
        DataRetriever dr = new DataRetriever();
        DataSet fg = dr.GetData(comboBox.Text);
        label1.Text = "No. of Rows:-    " + fg.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = fg.Tables[0];
    }

public class DataRetriever
{
    public void GetData(string text)
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=c://library//lib.mdb");

        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from entry where LTRIM(subjet)=?", cn);
        cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", text);
        DataSet fg = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(fg);
   }
}
```

If this is a complex application that you will want to look into multi-tier application design.

Comment: vs 2008 gives error when we use data retriecer error is..Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DataRetriever' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Projects\library\library\Form4.cs 54 13 library

Comment: Your project that contains the button2_click event must contain a reference to the project that contains the DataRetriever class.  And then the namespace must be referenced in a "using" clause at the top of the class that contains the button2_click event so that class knows where to find the DataRetriever class.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap the connection part with some class, but I'd recommend you to use ORM tools, such as [Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx), which is simple and flexible for working with different DBs.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should put your connection string in app.config under [connectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx).

When you open a connection make sure you'll closing it whatever happens:

```
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
 try
 {
   cn.Open();

   //db operations 
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: try catch block in using block? no it's not good practice.

Comment: that's what MSDN recommends http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your link is just a sample and is not recommendation, and clearly MSDN wants to show something else not how to use using block.